# How do you delete all documents from a MongoDB collection after each test?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I am trying to test an express/mongoose api using jest and supertest, but I can't figure out how to delete all documents after each test.
I have tried the following solutions, and more, to no avail:

```
afterEach(() => {
  User.deleteMany();
});
```

```
afterEach(async () => {
  await User.deleteMany();
});
```

```
afterEach(() => {
  User.deleteMany()
    .then((info) => {
      console.log(info);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/Leglaine/express-api-template) if it helps. The offending code is located in api/controllers/users.test.js

Comment: In our project we use different approach. We instead mock saves/updates so that we don't actually save/update documents into database as it might interfere with real data.

Comment: try `afterAll(async () => {
  await User.deleteMany();
});`

Comment: @dimitristseggenes thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but it still times out whenever I try to use async/await

Comment: @GytisTG That might be what I have to do, I will definitely look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();
  for (const collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});
```

this will delete all collections